# Renaming of uploaded image not working

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I'm trying to change the file name at the point of uploading. This image name is what I want to be inserted into the database `4f9e9118b753cIMAGE.jpeg`, but only `IMAGE.jpeg` (the original image name) is still retained in the file system. Below is the portion of code I am working with:

```
if (isset($_FILES['userupload']['name'])) {
   $uploaddir = "uploads/";

     switch($_FILES['userupload']['type']) {
                case "image/gif":
                case "image/jpeg":
                case "image/jpg":
                case "image/png":
          $uploaddir .= 'pictures/';
          break;
     }         

     foreach($_FILES as $userupload){   
          $t = uniqid();
          $type = $userupload['type'];
          $name = $userupload['name'];
          $size = $userupload['size']; 
          $image_name = $t."$name";


          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userupload']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $file)) {
              $query = "INSERT INTO users ( image_name ) VALUES ( '$image_name' )";  
              mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: @eggyal It's there (you have to scroll to the right - I've fixed the formatting a bit now), but the name variable is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert this line

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userupload"]["tmp_name"],$uploaddir.$image_name);
```

before the query